# Fast plane fitting to many points

Tags: performance, matlab, plane

I'm looking to fit a plane to a set of ~ 6-10k 3D points. I'm looking to do this as fast as possible, and accuracy is not the highest concern (frankly the plane can be off by +-10 degrees in any of the cardinal axes).

My current approach is to use best of best fit, but it's incredibly slow (I'm hoping to extract planes at a rate of about 10-50k times each time I run the algorithm, and at this rate it would finish in weeks, as opposed to hours) as it works on all possible combinations of 6000 points, so ~35,000,000,000 iterations, and frankly it has a much higher accuracy than I need.

Does anybody know of any weaker plane-fitting techniques that might speed my algorithm up considerably?

EDIT:

I've managed to get the number of iterations down to ~42k by creating planes at each possible 3D angle (stepping through at 5 degrees each time) and testing the existing points against these to find the best plane, instead of fitting planes to the points I have.

I'm sure there's something to be gained here by divide and conquering too, although I worry I could jump straight past the best plane.

Comment: Do you have access to the [Curve Fitting Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/curvefit/brviv3f-1.html#bs1cj4_-1)?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't, I'm stuck with vanilla MATLAB, although I have a lot of programming experience in general so I should be able to handle a fairly complex algorithm.

Comment: If accuracy isn't your main concern, try reducing the input complexity of your data. Run kmeans or something on the initial set of 6-10k points, and then fit the plane to the exemplars.

Comment: @Ansari: good idea. To improve performance even further, taking a random subset of points might be enough.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the standard plane equation `Ax + By + Cz + D = 0`, and write the equation as a matrix multiplication.  `P` is your unknown `4x1 [A;B;C;D]`

```
g = [x y z 1];  % represent a point as an augmented row vector
g*P = 0;        % this point is on the plane
```

Now expand this to all your actual points, an Nx4 matrix `G`.  The result is no longer exactly 0, it's the error you're trying to minimize.

```
G*P = E;   % E is a Nx1 vector
```

So what you want is the closest vector to the null-space of G, which can be found from the SVD.  Let's test:

```
% Generate some test data
A = 2;
B = 3;
C = 2.5;
D = -1;

G = 10*rand(100, 2);  % x and y test points
% compute z from plane, add noise (zero-mean!)
G(:,3) = -(A*G(:,1) + B*G(:,2) + D) / C + 0.1*randn(100,1);

G(:,4) = ones(100,1);   % augment your matrix

[u s v] = svd(G, 0);
P = v(:,4);             % Last column is your plane equation
```

OK, remember that P can vary by a scalar.  So just to show that we match:

```
scalar = 2*P./P(1);
P./scalar
```

ans =
    2.0000
    3.0038
    2.5037
   -0.9997

Answer (score 6):

In computer vision a standard way is to use RANSAC or MSAC, in your case;

1. Take 3 random points from the population
2. Calculate the plane defined by the 3 points
3. Sum the errors (distance to  plane) for all of the points to that plane.
4. Keep the 3 points that show the smallest sum of errors (and fall within a threshold).
5. Repeat N iterations (see RANSAC theory to choose N, may I suggest 50?)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [`griddata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/griddata.html) might be what you want. The link has an example in it.

If this doesn't work, maybe check out [`gridfit`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8998) on the MATLAB File Exchange. It's made to  match a more general case than `griddata`.

You probably don't want to be rolling your own surface fitting, as there's several well-documented tools out there.

Take the example from `griddata`:

```
x = % some values 
y = % some values
z = % function values to fit to

ti = % this range should probably be greater than or equal to your x,y test values
[xq,yq] = meshgrid(ti,ti);
zq = griddata(x,y,z,xq,yq,'linear'); % NOTE: linear will fit to a plane!
Plot the gridded data along with the scattered data.

mesh(xq,yq,zq), hold
plot3(x,y,z,'o'), hold off
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll look into this right away. I'm typically more from a CS background, so my surface-fitting math is a little behind. As such I'm more than happy to let somebody else's code do the job

Comment: Hmm my problem with griddata is that in order to get it to provide me with a plane, I have to (based off of their first example) tell it to generate zq using 4 points at (-1,-1), (-1,1), (1,-1), (1,1) (using 2:-2 - the bounds of the data set in the example - for some reason only returns NaN). Unfortunately this seems to guarantee that the corners of the plane will be at (-1,-1), (-1,1), (1,-1), (1,1) and it doesn't appear to be taking any more points into consideration. If I increase the number of points, I no longer get a plane.

Comment: @NickUdell Put some code you've tried in your answer so I can help you more.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the [consolidator](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8354) by John D'Errico. It aggregates the points within a given tolerance, this will allow to reduce the amount of data and increase the speed. You can also check John's [gridfit](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8998-surface-fitting-using-gridfit) function which is usually faster and more flexible than `griddata`

Answer (score 0):

If there are no outliers, just a little error in each point's location, then you can pick any 3 widely spaced points to define the plane. This is how I choose them to ensure they're far from colinear.

1. Find the 6 points with the maximum and minimum coordinate in each axis. This is a simple search through all points similar to finding an axis-aligned bounding box (AABB).
2. Identify which of those 3 pairs of points has the greatest separation in the direction of their axis (x, y or z) by subtracting their coordinates. This pair of points defines a line on the plane.
3. Find a 3rd point that's the furthest from this line. Since you don't require the absolute furthest point but just any far-away one, you don't have to do a full-blown 3D line-point-distance calculation but can project each point onto the plane normal to the long axis (x, y or z) and calculate its 2D distance from the line from 2).